# I'm using two monitors and buying my first graphics tablet. Does a two monitor setup affect what I should buy?

Tags: drawing-tablet, hardware-recommendation, monitor

Someone using a graphics tablet with two monitors, what observations have you made about how a two monitor setup might need to affect one's choice of graphics tablet.
I'm buying something like this to be clear about what I mean by tablet:

[image]

Comment: What would change with two monitors as opposed to one? Two together are essentially the same as a larger single one

Comment: @ZachSaucier aspect ratio? resolution? compatibility? Some tablets allow touching with fingers, I'm assuming this is used instead of a mouse to use a web browser and so on. Does this scale to multiple monitor setups?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wacon Intuos Pro at least can be configured so that by pressing a button on the tablet you can move between screens. This in many ways better than even having a very wide touch area for the whole two screens: you can move between screens much faster for example.

Answer (score 0):

nothing really changes when running 2 monitors. there are settings for the wacom (i've used the model pictured) that allow you to "crop" the working area of the tablet itself to mirror a single or dual monitor display. if you set it up to use on a dual monitor display, you'll effectively only use about half of the available working surface of the tablet.

every wacom i've ever used is highly customizable like that so i'm sure you can adjust it to work with your needs.